# How to pass multiple function parameters in an array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I want to pass multiple parameters to a function in an array. The parameters themselves are arrays of strings.

I have a function called `new_action()`, which I call in the following way:

```php
new_action(array('actions' => array('ACTION1','ACTION2'), 'tables' => array('table1','table2')));
```

and that function looks like this:

```php
public function new_action($params=array()) {
  $tables = array();
  $actions = array();

  if(count($params)) {
    foreach($params as $k => $v) {
      $tables  = ($k == 'tables')  ? $v : array();
      $actions = ($k == 'actions') ? $v : array();
    }

    // Do useful stuff with the variables here ...
    var_dump($tables);
    var_dump($actions);

    // ======== ACTUAL OUTPUT: ========
    // array(0) { }
    // array(0) { }

    // ======== EXPECTED OUTPUT: ========
    // array(2) { [0]=> string(6) "table1" [1]=> string(6) "table2" }
    // array(2) { [0]=> string(7) "ACTION1" [1]=> string(7) "ACTION2" }
  } 
}
```

As you can see, the value of `$v` inside the loop (the array of strings) is never being copied to the variable `$tables` or `$actions` outside the loop.

I think this is most likely a scope problem but looking at answers to other questions similar to this hasn't elucidated the solution for me.

**How do I refactor the code so that I can access those arrays stored in `$v` for each `$k` outside the `foreach` loop?**

Comment: with the foreach you are overwriting the existing values.

Comment: Thanks, @MarkusZeller. What a clumsy use of ternary assignment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The values are empty, because with the foreach you are overwriting existing values.

You can even write it more simple and use array shorthand syntax with brackets for better readability.

The [null coalesce operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) is syntactic sugar to avoid writing `isset()` and also is ternary. If it is set, it will return its contents, otherwise set to an empty array.

```php
new_action(['actions' => ['ACTION1', 'ACTION2'], 'tables' => ['table1', 'table2']]);

function new_action($p = array()): void {
    $tables  = $p['tables']  ?? [];
    $actions = $p['actions'] ?? [];

    var_dump($tables);
    var_dump($actions);
}
```

> array(2) { [0] => string(6) "table1" [1] => string(6) "table2" }
>   array(2) { [0] => string(7) "ACTION1" [1] => string(7) "ACTION2" }

Comment: very nice. First time I've come across this operator but it's certainly one I'll keep in my arsenal from now on. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is overwriting what was previously set because you are setting the values to `array()` when the key doesn't match `tables` or `actions`. So when  `$k == 'tables'`, `$actions` gets set back to an empty array.

Instead of the ternary operator, basically an `if/else`, refactor to just an `if` if you want to keep the loop:

```
foreach($params as $k => $v) {
        if ($k == 'tables') {
            $tables = $v;
        }
        if ($k == 'actions') {
            $actions = $v;
        }

    }
```

Or it can be condensed a bit by explicity checking for those keys at the start instead of looping:

```
function new_action($params=array()) {

    $tables = isset($params['tables']) ? $params['tables'] : array();

    $actions = isset($params['actions']) ? $params['actions'] : array();

    // Do useful stuff with the variables here ...
    var_dump($tables);
    var_dump($actions);

}
```

Comment: Ahh yes of course, it's been a long day! Thanks for explaining where I was overwriting and nice clean solution with the `isset()` method.

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't need the foreach to get that output:

```
public function new_action($params = array()) {
  $tables = array_key_exists('tables', $params) ? $params['tables'] : [];
  $actions = array_key_exists('actions', $params) ? $params['actions'] : [];

  // Do useful stuff with the variables here ...
  var_dump($tables); // Outputs => array(2) { [0]=> string(6) "table1" [1]=> string(6) "table2" }
  var_dump($actions); // Outputs => array(2) { [0]=> string(7) "ACTION1" [1]=> string(7) "ACTION2" }
  } 
}
```